# Styling progress element

Tags: css, html

I want  to change the color of progress bar value . I tried the following

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value
{
   background-color: #0063cc;
}
```

I tried it with Jsfiddle[I hope It's neither compiler nor browser]. But it works fine with Jsfiddle. But unfortunately , it doesn't work in chrome. Any suggestions?

Comment: I found the answer. error is with progress[value]

Comment: progress::-webkit-progress-bar
{
 background-color:#fff;
}
it ll work fine.

Comment: close the question as answered then

Comment: You can read this document @user3168736 : [http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/)